# Is it true that $Ry(\pi/2)\sigma_zRy(-\pi/2)=\sigma_x$?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, pauli-gates

I saw in a qiskit document that said $Ry(\pi/2)\sigma_zRy(-\pi/2)=\sigma_x$ To confirm this I decided to create the matrix representations of these operations and multiply them together to see if I get the correct matrix, but when I did this in numpy I didn't get the correct matrix

```
import numpy as np

sig_z = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])
rz = np.array([[np.exp(-1j*np.pi/4), 0],[0,np.exp(1j*np.pi/4)]])
print(np.matmul(rz, np.matmul(sig_z, -rz)))
```

This outputs

```
array([[-2.22044605e-16+1.j,  0.00000000e+00+0.j],
       [ 0.00000000e+00+0.j,  2.22044605e-16+1.j]])
```

While I was expecting

```
array([[0+0.j,  1+0.j],
       [1+0.j,  0+0.j]])
```

Am I doing something wrong?
For my $Rz$ gate I used the following model
$$
Rz(\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$ are supposed to be just standard Pauli operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ry$ gate is defined as
$$
Ry(\theta) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -\sin(\theta/2) \\
\sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence
$$
Ry(\pi/2) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4) \\
\sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4)
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Similarly for $Ry(-\pi/2)$ we have (*sine is odd function, so we only change sign before the sine, cosine is even, hence we left the sign unchanged*)
$$
Ry(-\pi/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now, by direct multiplication of the matrices we came to
$$
Ry(\pi/2)\,Z\,Ry(-\pi/2)=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = X.
$$

Here is calculation Octave (MatLab):

```
>> Ry = [cos(pi/4) -sin(pi/4); sin(pi/4) cos(pi/4)]
Ry =

   0.70711  -0.70711
   0.70711   0.70711

>> dgRy = [cos(-pi/4) -sin(-pi/4); sin(-pi/4) cos(-pi/4)]
dgRy =

   0.70711   0.70711
  -0.70711   0.70711

>> Z=[1 0; 0 -1];
>> Z
Z =

   1   0
   0  -1

>> Ry*Z*dgRy
ans =

  2.2204e-016  1.0000e+000
  1.0000e+000  -2.2204e-016
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `rz` in your code, while the identity you are asking about uses $R_y$

Here is a qiskit code to check the identity:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
import numpy as np

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)
circ.ry(-np.pi / 2, 0)
circ.z(0)
circ.ry(np.pi / 2, 0)

array_to_latex(Operator(circ))
```